# Exchange/Move a Oracle partition without interim table

Tags: oracle, move, partition

I would like to exchange the Oracle partition to another partitioned table. But to do that we are using interim non partitioned table. Can this be done in a different way?

Can't we exchange a partition from one partitioned table to another without using non-partitioned table as a medium? Can't we directly move a partition to target table?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to exchange so many different tables?

Comment: In any event, as long as you're on 12.2 or above, "create table for exchange" makes this trivial

Comment: Hi @ConnorMcDonald , Thanks for responding. Its our requirement to archive the old partitions for those tables.
Create table for exchange will help. But I'm trying to find a solution where we can directly move the partition from one partitioned table to another. instead of having a non-partitioned table as a medium.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to put a little API together to make this simple. In this example, T1 and T2 are matching, but T1 and T3 are not

```
SQL>
SQL> create table t1
  2  partition by list ( owner) automatic
  3  ( partition px values ('SYS') )
  4  as select * from dba_objects;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create table t2
  2  partition by list ( owner) automatic
  3  ( partition py values ('SYS') )
  4  as select * from dba_objects;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create table t3
  2  partition by list ( owner) automatic
  3  ( partition pz values ('SYSTEM') )
  4  as select * from dba_segments;

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create sequence seq;

Sequence created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  procedure exchange_par(
  3              p_table1 varchar2,
  4              p_table2 varchar2,
  5              p_table1_par varchar2,
  6              p_table2_par varchar2) is
  7    l_tab_cnt int;
  8    l_hash_cnt int;
  9    l_interim varchar2(100);
 10  begin
 11    select count(distinct tot), count(*)
 12    into   l_hash_cnt, l_tab_cnt
 13    from
 14      ( select table_name, sum(ora_hash(column_name)) tot
 15        from   user_tab_cols
 16        where  table_name in (p_table1,p_table2)
 17        group by table_name
 18      );
 19
 20    if l_tab_cnt != 2 or l_hash_cnt != 1 then
 21      raise_application_error(-20000,'Dead in the water');
 22    end if;
 23    l_interim := 'TMPTAB$'||seq.nextval;
 24
 25    begin
 26      execute immediate
 27        'drop table '||l_interim||' purge';
 28    exception
 29      when others then
 30        if sqlcode = -942 then null; else raise; end if;
 31    end;
 32
 33    execute immediate
 34      'create table '||l_interim||' for exchange with table '||p_table1;
 35
 36    execute immediate
 37      'alter table '||p_table1||' exchange partition '||p_table1_par||
 38      ' with table '||l_interim;
 39
 40    execute immediate
 41      'alter table '||p_table2||' exchange partition '||p_table2_par||
 42      ' with table '||l_interim;
 43
 44    execute immediate
 45      'drop table '||l_interim||' purge';
 46
 47  end;
 48  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> exec exchange_par('T1','T2','PX','PY');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> exec exchange_par('T1','T3','PX','PZ');
BEGIN exchange_par('T1','T3','PX','PZ'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Dead in the water
ORA-06512: at "MCDONAC.EXCHANGE_PAR", line 20
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
SQL>
SQL>
SQL>
```

Can make this as robust as you like with more conditions etc.